# remove duplicated row and increase weight columns with vba

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I'm trying to add a weight for source and target cell...so I do this :

```
  ' .Resize(, 4) = Array("Source", "Target", "Label", "Weight")
    .........

    Range(sStartingCellOutput).Offset(lRowOffset, lColOffset).Resize(1,4).Value = _
  Array(sq(lUser_1, 2), sqq(lUser_2), rTopic.Value,1)'
```

then the result is like this :

```
  'Source   Target  Label   Weight
    2955    7733    1       1
    7733    2955    1       1
    2961    6498    2       1
    6498    2961    2       1
    2961    2962    3       1
    2961    2962    3       1
    2962    2961    3       1
    2962    2961    3       1'
```

But I didn't want to show the duplicates row (source and target) i want to remove the duplicate and increase the weight ...
like this :

```
    ' Source    Target  Label   Weight
      2955      7733        1       1
      7733      2955        1       1
      2961      6498        2       1
      6498      2961        2       1
      2961      2962        3       2
      2962      2961        3       2'
```

any help for that ??

thanks

Comment: Do you want to run a macro afterwards or to change the existing so it does this automatically?

Comment: i want to do it automatically when i run the macro code ...! :s

Comment: check the data line by line... if 2 lines match up, then increase the upper one by the weight of the lower and delete the lower line... have you tried that?

Comment: no I will try ..thanks :)

Comment: can you give me an example (match up ) ...it dosent work with me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an example: (asuming `A1=Source` / `B1=Target` / `C1=Label` / `D1=Weight`)

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Long, j As Long
i = 2
With ActiveSheet
  While Len(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value & .Cells(i, 3).Value)
    j = i + 1
    While Len(.Cells(j, 1).Value & .Cells(j, 2).Value & .Cells(j, 3).Value)
      If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(j, 1).Value And .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(j, 2).Value And .Cells(i, 3).Value = .Cells(j, 3).Value Then
        .Cells(i, 4).Value = .Cells(i, 4).Value + .Cells(j, 4).Value
        .Rows(j).Delete
      End If
      j = j + 1
    Wend
    i = i + 1
  Wend
End With
```

would do exactly what you want (in a slow way)

Comment: sorry :$ another Q : can i make this code work in vba in access ?? it worked in excel (csv file ) for small data ...but it hangs for large data ..so i used access to load all file in csv and i want to run vba code in it but it didn't worked ...:S ..Does vba code in excel is different in access or what? ...Thanks so much...I'm sorry for asking too much ..

Comment: It is... cus you have datasets which are like... umm... a collection of property's, while an excelsheet is more like a 2D Array. How large is the csv file in kb/mb?

Comment: csv file one of them is 1million KB ..:S

Comment: 1 GB.. then better use Access... anyways :D or loop the file line by line (which is faster, but may leave chaos if anything goes wrong :/